# Google Chrome cannot be installed on Windows XP because "the version is not suported"! What should I do?

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, installation

When I am trying to install Chrome on my laptop that has Windows XP installed, it says that the installation failed because my version is not supported. What should I do?

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you trying to install?  (The RC's don't always work on all versions of all operating systems).

Comment: Use firefox perhaps

Comment: What service pack of Windows XP is it? It's not uncommon for software to require SP3, and there are many people who never upgraded to XP SP3.

Comment: @techie007 - I don't know what version it is. I have downloaded it from this page: http://www.google.com/chrome/index.html?hl=en&brand=CHMI&installdataindex=homepagepromo but they don't say there what version it is.

Comment: @Myrddin Emrys - I don't know which pack of Windows XP is installed on my laptop. Can you please tell me how I could find that out?

Comment: @Akash - I am already using FireFox, but I want to try Chrome.

Comment: Right click on "My Computer" and select Properties, this will show the service pack level.

Comment: Hotkey for that is WINDOWS + PAUSE/BREAK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to Google](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95411), Chrome requires Windows XP Service Pack 2 or higher. I would recommend upgrading XP to the newest service pack (SP3) for security and software compatibility.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/help/learn-how-to-install-windows-xp-service-pack-3-sp3

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please tell me how I could find out which pack of XP I already have installed on my laptop? Also, before installing SP3, do I need to get rid of the current one?

Comment: @Brilliant - System Properties Window

Comment: WINDOWS + PAUSE/BREAK is the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

To find out which Service Pack Click Start --> Control panel --> System.
Under the general tab, System info will show the installed SP.
If you are installing SP3, no need to uninstall previous version

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make google chrome portable using softwares like [Cameyo visualization tool](http://www.cameyo.com/) that makes any application portable. You can then run chrome for your usb. You can do this if you really want chrome but not willing to update your service pack.